# PHP isn't linking MySQL shared library correctly on build

Tags: php, mysql, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build PHP on my new computer with this configuration:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LIBS=-lresolv
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-ldap=/usr --with-kerberos=/usr --enable-cli --with-zlib-dir=/usr --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-sockets --with-iodbc=/usr --with-curl=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --sysconfdir=/private/etc --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-openssl=/usr --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl=/usr --without-pear --with-libxml-dir=/usr --with-iconv=/usr/local --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/Cellar --with-png-dir=/usr/X11 --with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11 --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/Cellar --enable-pcntl
```

The configuration runs fine, but when I try to run "make" it ends up at this error:

```
Generating phar.phar
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mdiamond/Downloads/php-5.3.8/sapi/cli/php
  Reason: image not found
make: *** [ext/phar/phar.phar] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

This is pretty bizarre, considering I specified "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib" and libmysqlclient.18.dylib is in that path. It seems the linker is looking for libmysqlclient.18.dylib without a path (in the root?). I also ran otool on my php binary and got this:

```
/usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.13.0)
/usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.18.0)
libmysqlclient.18.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.8.0)
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.2.0)
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.2.0)
/usr/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib (compatibility version 17.0.0, current version 17.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.0.0)
/usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 46.0.0)
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.3.0)
/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 46.1.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
/usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.24.0)
```

Note how libmysqlclient is the only library without a path. Does anyone know how I can solve this? Am I running the configure wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I think it was related to the fact that `/usr/local/mysql` is symlinked to `/usr/local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64` on my computer (MySQL installed via DMG). Changing `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to use the fully qualified path seemed to get `make` to work for me.

However, I did encounter a follow-up problem during the `make install` process. The same error message came up during the `Installing PEAR environment` step. The solution to *that* issue was to do this beforehand:

```
install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib \
  /usr/local/mysql-5.5.15-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib \
  /path/to/php-5.3.8/sapi/cli/php
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar thing happened to me when I tried to compile PHP 5.4.16 together with MariaDB 5.5 on MacOS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. During `make`, the process stopped unexpectedly with this error report:

```
Undefined symbols:
 "_res_9_dn_expand", referenced from:
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _php_parserr in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
 "_res_9_search", referenced from:
 _zif_dns_check_record in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
 "_res_9_init", referenced from:
 _zif_dns_check_record in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
 "_res_9_dn_skipname", referenced from:
 _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_mx in dns.o
 _zif_dns_get_record in dns.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

I'm using a whole bunch of non-standard directories for running my server (apache with PHP-CGI), so my configure settings are somewhat odd and unhelpful to others. They have worked for the whole 5.4 branch of PHP with MariaDB 5.2, and only today did it stop working as expected.

Thanks to your postings, this is what I came up with to get it to compile and install successfully again (of course, change paths depending on own requirements):

1. prior to `compile`, set the path to the database lib directory:

   `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/customserver/maria55/lib`
2. run `./compile` with options as required
3. run `make`
4. run this to fix the broken path to the mysql client library inside both the CGI and CLI binaries:

   `install_name_tool -change install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /customserver/maria55/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /sources/php-5.4.16/sapi/cli/php`

   `install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /customserver/maria55/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /sources/php-5.4.16/sapi/cgi/php-cgi`
5. run `sudo make install`

Hope this is helpful for other in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

The second `_php_parserr in dns.o` bug (mentioned [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49332), and [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49267)) can also be resolved by doing the following:

Edit your `Makefile` and add the following flag to the `EXTRA_LIBS =` section (in addition to the other flags already there):

```
EXTRA_LIBS = -lsresolv
```

Though if you can resolve it by changing your paths, as mentioned above, that would be preferable.